# Preventing iPad Pro from getting hot during usage

Tags: ipad

My iPad Pro 2018 gets quite hot during usage. I've noticed that this occurs around 50% brightness (not even 100%). If I turn it lower to, say, 10-20%, it doesn't heat up anymore. I assume this heating is partially due to the thinness of the device, which conducts heat very easily.

This heat is rather uncomfortable on my hand while I write on my iPad. Is there any way to get rid of this heat without lowering the brightness too much? I don't want to reduce the brightness due to legibility.

There are some "heatsink" cases for iPhones; is there anything similar for the iPad anywhere?

Comment: Is that a cellular model ? that can heat up the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strange way that I've gotten around this issue is by placing the iPad on a large heat sink—basically anything that can conduct heat really easily. An example is a laptop (that is turned off!) which can take in a lot of the heat generated from the iPad's body. The iPad needs to be placed in direct contact with the heat sink.

This actually *significantly* cools down the screen of the iPad, which allows me to place my hand comfortable on the screen while writing. It's still warm, but at least not burning hot.